# How many pointers fit in stack?

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

The compiler I'm concerned about is GCC 32bit for the x86 architecture. My current project requires massive integer arrays, and I am trying to avoid heap as much as possible.

Comment: The stack size is configurable, but stack allocation of large arrays is unusual and almost certainly the wrong approach. Why are you trying to avoid the heap? Allocating a large array on the heap will be much faster than whatever you do *with* that array (whether it's on the heap or the stack).

Comment: Unfortunately, the capacity of the call stack is not queryable from within the language. While the total stack size may be configurable in your compiler, the *available* stack size depends on how deep down the call chain you are. To some extent, you can never know whether it's actually OK to call a function in C. You just know that "reasonable" programs just work.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the heap?